# Converting mapsforge .map file to OSM or shp

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, mapsforge

I have found solution for converting OSM file into .map file but is there a way for converting .map file back to osm or shp or any other well-known vector file type?

by .map file i mean [mapsforge .map file](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Specification-Binary-Map-File.md), not mapinfo .map file

Comment: Is the `.map` file a [MapInfo binary](http://www.gdal.org/drv_mitab.html)? If so you can use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to convert it to pretty much anything.

Comment: No, not mapinfo .map file, i've edited question and add more info

Comment: Maybe there is a different solution to your problem. Can you tell us the reason why you want to convert the map back into OSM's format?

Comment: i want to extract polylines coordinates from that file. I think it is possible using official mapsforge library and some coding, but i was seeking for a more straightforward solution.

Comment: But why don't you extract this kind of information from OSM in the first place? Isn't your mapsforge map file based on OSM data?

Comment: I do not access to original OSM file now. I think i should wait to get access to original file then...

Answer (score 1):

reading the mapsforge-dev mailinglist for a long time now, I never came accross such a conversion feature.

I assume that OSM data -> mapsforge mapfiles is a oneway processing.

But you can try to ask on your own there,
see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mapsforge-dev

(I only found one similar question there from 2013, but no answer.)